# Jenkins - Get path to git Repository on slave

Tags: git, jenkins, kubernetes

I'm currently running Jenkins on Kubernetes with Helm: 
After spawning a Jenkins slave and cloning the git Repository, I try to access a folder in this git repository:

```
def chart_dir = "${WORKSPACE}/flowchart"
```

After that I perform a `helm lint ${chart_dir}`. Unfortunately this does not return a result, since the folder is empty. My guess is, that the workspace path is incorrect.

Does anybody know a way to: 
**1. List all the files in the Folder on a slave machine 
2. Get the proper workspace path on a slave machine?**

Greetings 
J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would need a little more information such as a Jenkinsfile and the script you're executing.

But assuming you're using the git plugin to clone a repo and then execute a script.

The working directory at the time of executing the script is the root of your repository.

The $WORKSPACE environment variable gives you the absolute path to the jenkins workspace (usually /var/lib/jenkins/workspace depending on your setup)

So executing:

> helm lint ./flowchart

Should work just fine.

You can find more information about the exposed environment variables here:
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin